# React native login instagram only login with account register client id

Tags: react-native

I'm use [react-native-instagram-login](https://github.com/hungdev/react-native-instagram-login) to create sample login Instagram.
I'm using account Abc@gmail.com to create client id and when login with Abc@gmail.com it's ok but when I login with another account it show error: {"error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "code":400,"error_message": "Your are not a sandbox user of this client"}.
It's mean when my application not public in google play or app store I only can login with my account register client id? If it is error how I can't fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, you need to get your app reviewed by Instagram.